# 135mm Hub in 141mm Boost QR

Tags: hub, internally-geared-hub, dropouts

I may be barking up the wrong tree, but I have the following project in mind.

I'm looking to buy a bike ([Giant Fathom E+EX](https://mtbdatabase.com/bikes/2022/giant/fathom/2022-giant-fathom-e-ex/)) that is listed  as having 141 QR Boost drop-outs in the rear.  I want to convert to an Internal Geared Hub ([Enviolo Trekking](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cApEqa6vw-U2adRgqbOIBpdq_tSPfGba/view)).

The IGH has the 'standard' 135mm width, axel diameter is the typical 10mm AFAIK.

141mm QR Boost is as far as I've understood, a 10mm diameter drop-out.

My hypothese is the IGH should fit if I add 3mm thick washers on the hub axel (one each side) just before the dropout (and possibly a 3mm thick adapter for the brake disc).

Could this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer about the direct question QR141 vs 135: installing 3mm washers on each side will also means that the axle will be 3mm shorter in the drop-out. The brake won't be positioned correctly either, and the chainline won't match, as the chainring is positioned for boost hubs (probably not so critical with chains though).

On the idea itself, since you write "looking to buy", I would ask why not buy a bike equipped directly with an Enviolo hub? In this segment, I'm only aware of the Canyon Pathlite:ON 8 SUV or the Precede:ON 7 (if you don't need the suspension) — and many Riese&Muller as well, but these are usually more expensive. The Pathlite costs 1000€ more than the Giant, I would not be surprised that if you count all costs, it won't be so different (hub, shifter, wheel or relacing the wheel, labour,...) and as bonus it has a belt instead of a chain (you need special frames for belts). It also has a suspended dropper post, that is very nice. Note that the Canyon uses the Heavy Duty hub on this bike, that is compatible with 12x148 thru-axle, not the Trekking, so if you want to make the conversion after purchasing the bike, better to take one with this standard, that is in fact very common (141mm QR is quite rare).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The reason I'm coming up with silly ideas is because none of limited "off-the-shelf" options work for me. The Pathlite:ON 8 SUV is over-budget (1.5k€ more than current Giant price) and I'm not taken with the frame-design or how the battery goes in/out, and I like neither of the 2 colours available.
The Vado 5 IGH from Specialized is more expensive, not quite what I'm after an I don't want an automatic in any case. The Vado 3.0 IGH is affordable but also doesn't quite have the battery capacity or motor power I'm after.

Comment: ... I really like the Tero 4.0 EQ but there's no IGH version (even though it's the same frame as the Vado).
Other IGH eBikes are urban or touring style which isn't really what I'm after.

Comment: I also looked at converting a cube hybrid performance 625 allroad (even cheaper than the giant) but I don't think that wouldn't work - has a 135mm wide hub but I think its thru-axel so neither the enviolo TR or heavy duty would fit.

Comment: Regarding the mechanics of my original "idea". The TR has 183mm axel width so I thought there would still be plenty room for the no-turn washer and nut.
I thought that a 3mm thick adapter between brake disc and hub, with poss. adjusting the caliper position a bit would have worked.
I was thinking the the sprocket of the hub would have been roughly where one of the low-mid gears of the cassette would have been.
Oh well.

Comment: @Pete Cube has two trekking bikes: Touring with QR135 and Kathmandu with TA148, so both should work (with the trekking, and the heavy duty respectively). But have you counted all the costs for the conversion? The hidden one is the wheel: you'll need to have a custom built wheel for that, so new spokes + rim + labour.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  - I'll have look, though I'm wanting more crossover/"suv" than trekking, 29" wheels preferred over 28/27.5

I was hoping that the rim would be re-usable... I'm blessed with a good LFBS regarding labour.
Regarding costs: I can theoretically ride the bike 'as is' for a few of months until I save for a conversion - roughly 600€ I've reckoned.

Comment: The difference between cross over and trekking is just the tires in practice (and the look). Just out of curiosity, what is the interest in the Enviolo hub compared to a Shimano Nexus for instance? The added value of CVT as I understand it is mostly appreciable when coupled with the Automatiq module, but without that, I've never felt a requirement to have "more speeds".

Comment: The rim is reusable, if you have the same amount of spokes. But it may better to sell the wheel as it is (or keep it), and buy a new rim.

Comment: My previous (non E) bike had a Nexus 7 - a main motivation to go back to a IGH :-)  I'd prob. go for a Nexus if I could. The Enviolo hubs (from Trekkig up) have higher torque ratings - the Nexus 5e is only for 55nM. They also have a larger ratio range.  5 gears would be too few I feel (7's my minimum) and I'm curious to how the stepless shifting is.

Comment: Kalkhoff has some trekking ebikes with the Nexus 5e and Bosch performance line motors but I suspect they've limited the power-output down from 65nm to 55nm.